# Routing in angularjs based on an attribute

Tags: angularjs

I want to route based on a user type in my angular app.

So if user is Admin, then should be redirected to admin.html and if user then user.html based on the value coming of user type from database after login.

In this I want to add condition:

```
.when('/dashboard', {        
    title: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'partials/User.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use .run function and check the user there and redirect to conditional page using $location.

```
.when('/user', {        
    title: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'partials/User.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'    
}).when('/admin', {        
    title: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'partials/Admin.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'    
})
```

from run function

```
.run(function($location){
    console.log("run")
    var user = "user";
    if(user === "Admin"){
      $location.path("/admin")
    }else{
       $location.path("/user")
    }
  })
```

from controller

```
.controller('authCtrl',function($location){
    console.log("controller")
     var user = "admin";
    if(user === "admin"){
      $location.path("/admin")
    }else{
       $location.path("/user")
    }
  })
```

Comment: $routeParams.user = Data.usertype;
                if($routeParams.user.equals('U'))
                    {
                                        $location.path('user');

                    }
                else{
                                    $location.path('dashboard');

                }

Comment: Yes it should work but if you want it before controller loading then you can use angular.run function and redirect from there.

Comment: Need to do through controller itself but in controller error is coming her is Code :

Comment: app.controller('authCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) {
    //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.signup = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (customer) {
        Data.post('login', {
            customer: customer
        }).then(function (results) {
            Data.toast(results);

Comment: if (results.status == "success") {
               $routeParams.user = Data.usertype;
                if($routeParams.user.equals('U'))
                    {
                                        $location.path('user');

                    }
                else{
                                    $location.path('dashboard');

                }
                //$location.path('dashboard');
            }
        });
    };

Comment: Almost got it you tell me how i can use this:$routeParams.user.equals('U') Its saying equals is not a method.How can i perform this test?

Comment: there is no **equals** **function** in **javascript** as it exists in other languages like **java** you can do like this routeParams.user === "U"

Comment: At last it worked.As ia am newbie in Angular so took some time Thanks Jorawar

Comment: Good you are welcome.. and let me know if you need help in future :-)

Comment: Sure Jorawar. I will ask for help when needed

Comment: Jorawar how can i achieve nested routing?means in user.html if i have three sections  user/a user/b user/c?

Comment: You mean same page just navigating to different section? feels wrong site to chat :-) my fb id SinghJorawar1010

Answer (score 0):

I did it using ui-router and not ng-router, but you can still check my answer here:

[Check if user has permission to access specific states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525653/check-if-user-has-permission-to-access-specific-states/38530104#38530104)

Basically I build a service and validated if user has access to that state else, redirect the user to another state.

The service was being called in the run function on every state change.

Answer (score 0):

In your login controller inject the $routeParams dependency, then affect to a $routeParams variable the value of user ( simple user or admin ) like this

```
$routeParams.user = data.user;
```

Now in configure your route like this

```
.when('/:user', {
      title: 'dashboard',
      templateUrl:'partials/:user.html'
      controller: 'authCtrl'  
 });
```

so if it's simple user you are going to be redirected to partials/user.html and if it's the admin you are going to be redirected to partials/admin.html .

Comment: what this means :user?

Comment: This is the $routeParams variable , so :user refer to $routeParams.user variable from your controller.